# Solving for $x$ in this simple differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=2\dfrac{\sqrt{2g(\sin c- \sin x)}}{\sqrt{l}}$. $g$, $c$, and $l$ are all constants. Is there a way to solve for $x$ in terms of $t$ here? Once I did separation of variables and plugged in the integral into wolframalpha I got a pretty horrendous integral on the side with $x$. I was wondering if it could perhaps be simplified especially when you solve for $x$ in terms of $t$. Thanks

Comment: Nonlinear, inhomogeneous, implicit ODE? Maybe it's doable, but my gut feeling says NO.

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to solve pendulum problem? There's no closed form for that in elementary functions.

Comment: Yup lol how did you know? Did you try it once yourself too?

Comment: I know because the ODE looks familiar. I learned being in high school that this ODE cannot be solved in elementary functions. You can use elliptic integral though. Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29#Arbitrary-amplitude_period) for more info.

Comment: Haha I am in high school and I'm trying to do this. Thanks for letting me know that this doesn't have a closed solution. By the way what's ODE?

Comment: Ordinary Differential Equation. That's the thing you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Kaster This isn't the pendulum equation; the sine is under a square root and the first derivative is a second. However I am confident there is no nice solution to this problem.

Comment: No, this is exactly the pendulum equation, you can even look at the link on wikipedia, although they have cosine instead of sine. Either maybe they picked a different angle or I made a mistake. And I know this is not $dx/dt$ as in tangential velocity. I know this is $d theta/dt$, it's just easier to put x than find a theta symbol somewhere and copy and paste it every time.

Comment: @ABlumenthal cosine becomes sine if take angle from horizontal line instead of vertical. I didn't get about second part with first and second derivatives. If you follow the link I provided, the equations is the same except the angle and factor of $2$, which I believe appeared by mistake or some assumptions that weren't put in question.

Comment: @Ovi The code for $\theta$ is "\" followed by "theta".

Comment: @Kaster You're completely right. This and the form I had in my head are the same equation. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's OK for you to use the Taylor series approximation of $\sin(x)$ as $\sin(x) \approx x$ (for small x), then you can rewrite your equation as

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=2\dfrac{\sqrt{A - 2gx}}{\sqrt{l}}$

where $A = 2g\sin(c)$.

You then have a more straightforward separable equation with the solution

$x(t) = \frac{Al - g^2(c_1 +2t)^2}{2gl}$.

This is called the "small angle approximation."

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the pendulum equation for small angles but I was trying to find this for a physics problem involving a lever falling from above the horizontal. However, from the comments I found out that this does not have a closed form in elementary functions, and it is beyond my purposes to get a really messy answer to this question.